# refer to array from SELECT clause in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, where-clause

I have the following two tables:

```
create table person
(
    identifier  integer     not null,
    name        text        not null,
    age         integer     not null,

    primary key(identifier)
);

create table agenda
(
    identifier  integer     not null,
    name        text        not null,

    primary key(identifier)
);
```

They are joined with the following table:

```
create table person_agenda
(
    person_identifier   integer not null,
    agenda_identifier   integer not null,

    primary key(person_identifier, agenda_identifier),
    foreign key(person_identifier) references person(identifier),
    foreign key(agenda_identifier) references agenda(identifier)
);
```

I am trying to refer to an array, as definied in the `SELECT` clause, in the `WHERE` clause.

The following works:

```
select identifier, name, array(select identifier from agenda a, person_agenda pa where person_identifier = p.identifier and identifier = agenda_identifier and name = '...') as r
from person p;
```

This does not:

```
select identifier, name, array(select identifier from agenda a, person_agenda pa where person_identifier = p.identifier and identifier = agenda_identifier and name = '...') as r
from person p
where array_length(r, 1) >= 1;
```

It says that `r` is not a known column. How can I refer to this array in the `WHERE` clause?

The purpose of my second query is to:

- omit persons without agendas (by filtering on `array_length()` >= 1)
- get all agenda identifiers, so I can fetch their information in a subsequent query without having to filter again (on field `agenda.name` in my example above) (by projecting the array in the `SELECT` clause)

The first bullet can be done with a simple join. But, for the first bullet in combination with the second bullet, I need some kind of aggregation on the agenda identifiers. I thought arrays would be useful for this.

**edit**

According to user Saba, this is not possible. Thanks for your feedback.

Is the following query a good alternative?

```
select   person.identifier, person.name, array_agg(agenda.identifier)
from     person, person_agenda, agenda
where    person.identifier = person_identifier and
         agenda.identifier = agenda_identifier and
         agenda.name = '...'
group by person.identifier;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alias cant be used in WHERE clause, if you want to use the alias in your WHERE clause, you need to wrap it in a subquery or CTE. Because query will be executed in the following order:

```
FROM
ON
JOIN
**WHERE**
GROUP BY
WITH CUBE or WITH ROLLUP
HAVING
**SELECT**
DISTINCT
ORDER BY
TOP
```

Try something like this:

```
SELECT 
FROM    (
        select identifier, name, array(select identifier from agenda a, person_agenda pa where person_identifier = p.identifier and identifier = agenda_identifier and name = '...') as r
        from person p
        ) AS per
where array_length(r) >= 1;
```

Your case seems straight forward, the below one should work for you:

```
select   person.identifier, person.name, array_agg(agenda.identifier)
from     person, person_agenda, agenda
where    person.identifier = person_identifier and
         agenda.identifier = agenda_identifier and
         agenda.name = '...'
group by person.identifier, person.name;
```

Comment: Thanks. The `WHERE` is indeed executed before the `SELECT`. How can I rewrite my second query in a subquery, which still meets the two bullets?

Comment: Thanks for your edit. Wrappig in a subquery is pretty clever. This works also!

Comment: Which solution is advised? Yours or mine (see my edit)? Should I create a new question for this?

Comment: We came up with the same query;). I am not grouping on `person.name` also, since `person.identifier` is the primary key of table `person`. That is correct?